# How can I change the iphone and ipad device settings -> email address and name programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, iphone-developer-program

Now I'm working in iphone app. In that app I'm using google calendar. In iphone,ipad and ipod devices, I want to add the email address and name.

In our device goto settings->mail,contacts,calendar->gmail->account->. Here we have editing the mail address and name manually.

Now i want to add these detail programmatically. If user enter the mail address and name i want to set it programatically. I have attached the screen shot for above detail steps.

[image]

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: I didn't quite get it right: do you want to show the placeholder for creating an account, or what?

Comment: @Pheel not a place holder. we entering the gmail account (our own) and name manually know. But i need to add that account mail id and password via programming. In my app i have to get the account mail id and password from the user. And  i have to show in that above mentions screen shot places. For (e.x) Name means: Kannan and Email and description is my mail id. I want to add like this

Comment: @Pheel have you got it my question?

Answer (score 0):

just set identifier in settings bundle for each field then do the following

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.name.text forKey:id_name];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

where value is user entered value and key already set in settings bundle identifier(id_name) k if any doubt let me know @kannan

Comment: @kannan, tell me one thing, you did not tell, how to change email id and where to set key name in setting bundle